# Proof involving fibonacci number: $ \binom{n}{1}F_1+\binom{n}{2}F_2+\binom{n}{3}F_3+\cdots+\binom{n}{n-1}F_{n-1}+F_n=F_{2n}, $

Tags: combinatorics, summation, fibonacci-numbers

**Problem:** Prove that
$$
\binom{n}{1}F_1+\binom{n}{2}F_2+\binom{n}{3}F_3+\cdots+\binom{n}{n-1}F_{n-1}+F_n=F_{2n},
$$
where $F_n$ denotes the $n$th Fibonacci number.

I tried induction, but I didn't know what to do for $n=k+1$.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569873/fibonacci-combinatorial-identity

Comment: You are welcome :)

Comment: The question you posed is a result due to the Italian mathematician Ernesto Cesaro. It may be of interest to some that there's actually a statement that generalizes Cesaro's result:
$$
\binom{n}{0}F_m+\binom{n}{1}F_{m+1}+\cdots+\binom{n}{n}F_{m+n}=F_{m+2n},
$$
where $m$ and $n$ are non-negative integers.