# Prove the following identity (Fibonacci numbers)

Tags: combinatorics, fibonacci-numbers

> $$\binom{n}{0}F_0+\binom{n}{1}F_1+\binom{n}{2}F_2+...+\binom{n}{n}F_n=F_{2n}$$
>   Where $F_n$ represents Fibonacci numbers. Can someone please aid me in solving this proof?

Comment: Please explain what you have tried so far and also what you know about Fibonacci numbers. E.g. have you checked thsi for some finite values of $n$? And do you know a closed formula for $F_n$?

Comment: Probable duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112752/prove-binomn0f-0-binomn1f-1-binomn2f-2-cdots-binomnnf-n-f and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569873/fibonacci-combinatorial-identity-f-2n-n-choose-0-f-0-n-choose-1-f-1.

Comment: This question also appeared at this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1905464/).