# Fibonacci numbers and binomial theroem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fibonacci-numbers, binomial-theorem

So I am trying to prove

$$\sum_{i=0}^n{nCi×F_i} = F_{2n}$$
Such that
$$nCi = \frac {n!}{i!×(n-i)!}$$
And $F_i$ is the ith value of the fibonacci sequence such that $F_0 = 1$ and $F_1 = 1$

I have stared at this problem maybe 3 hours so far and I have found so far $$\sum_{i=0}^{n/2}{(n-i)Ci} = F_{n+1}$$

and that

$$F_{2n} = F_{n+1} × F_n + F_n × F_{n-1}$$

but so far I haven't quite found a way to use these patters for a proof. Am I on the right track? If not could anyone spare a student a hint? :).

Thank you

Also I apologize for the poor format of my math expressions, I am still new to the site and I couldn't get any syntax I personallu knew to format.

Comment: In the first expression, do you mean $nCi$ ?

Comment: Yes I just finished the edits I believe

Comment: This question recently appeared at this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1532868/).

Comment: There are three answers to the earlier question, using three different approaches.